# creating singleton using module level const - typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created Singleton class in Typescript as below -

```
export class Service {
    
    public static readonly I = new Service();
    
    public post(url: string): string {}
}
```

Caller use it like `Service.I.post('url');`.

I got recommendation to use `module-level const`. What is it? How can I create Singleton type class using `Module-level const`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, the "singleton" object is a property of the exported `Service` class, as a static member. The Service class, as it is currently, is quite weird because it doesn't have a constructor, nor any instance properties - this is what some with OOP backgrounds may naturally tend towards, to put everything in a class, but it doesn't make much sense in JavaScript.

What the recommendation is saying is to declare the singleton with `const` outside the class, and export that singleton:

```
class Service {
  // stuff
}
export const service = new Service();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just, a module-level constant :)

```
class Interal {
  // Stuff here
}

const instance = new Internal()

export default instance
```